# Node.js Cluster on a multi-core system

Tags: node.js

Currently, I'm using the cluster module on my `node.js` apps to prevent the apps from crashing and exiting on `unhandledExcpetion`. However, I found this snippet of code that is alleged to take advantage of multi-core systems

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < require('os').cpus().length; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
} else {
    http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end('hello world\n');
    }).listen(3008);
}
```

#### Questions:

- Does this have any benefits?
- Does it handle load balancing?
- If it does some load balancing how does it compare to load balancing via `NGINX`?
- Is there any arguments against this?

---

*Note: I tried to look this technique up to avoid asking a redundant question, but honestly I don't know what to search for since I don't know what this technique is called*

Answer (score 0):

First i suggest you to fork new process on `exit`.

```
cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    console.log('Starting new process.....Since a worker died')
    cluster.fork();//new process.
});
```

So cluster allows all the process to share same port.

1. Yes, it has benefits since it utilizes all cores available on the
   machine.
2. Yes, It does load balancing in round robin fashion among the cluster
   processes.
3. Nginx allows you to balance among multiple servers.(running on
   different machines or ports).
4. See below.

> For example say you have 4 machines and each machines have 4
>   cores.What you can do is run 4 servers on these 4 machines in cluster
>   mode.This will give you inner level load balancing among multiple
>   cores while using nginx this will give outer level load balancing
>   among the machines.

Still(for last 2 questions) there is lot of discussions and arguments out there on web. [see here](http://stackabuse.com/setting-up-a-node-js-cluster/).